# Mean of repeated samples

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, sampling, mean

Let's assume we have random variables $X_1\sim N(\mu_1,1),\cdots,X_n\sim N(\mu_n,1)$. Now we take one sample from each and get $X_1 = x_1,\cdots,X_n = x_n$. We order them and calculate the mean of top $d$ values. Let's label the $d$ associated random variables $X^{(1)},\cdots, X^{(d)}$. Now we take another sample of $X^{(1)},\cdots, X^{(d)}$, and compute the sample mean. Is the mean this time expected to be smaller than the first time? Is there a formal proof?

Comment: Do you mean for the $\mu$ to be different for each $X_i$?

Comment: Yes each $X_i$ has its own mean